# Linearization of a non linear contraint (min between two positive variables)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, minimization, linearization

I have the following restriction: min(A, B), where A and B are always positive. It's very simple to linearize this using binaries, but I have a NLP problem and I don't know how to approach this.

I have tried some approximations as max(-A,0) = (-A + sqrt(-A^2 + error^2)/2 but they don't really apply to my problem.

Comment: `min(A,B)` is not a constraint ("restriction"), but rather an expression. Linearization depends on how this expression is used in the model.

Comment: You're right. x = min(A,B) and it's a constraint of the problem. It comes in the objective function as min costs = ... + delta (x - p)*cost, where p is a parameter. So my problem is to linearize x = min(A,B). I've also tried x <= A, x <= B, x >= 0 and subtracting x on the objective function, multiplying it by a very small number and it doesn't work.

Comment: Choosing a formulation depends quite a lot on the details. Without more information, we can say that the constraint  `x=min(y,z)` is non-convex. Depending on the precise form of the objective (and the signs of the parameters), we may be able to do better,

Comment: f course. I'll try to detailed it the best I can. 

Vn stands for every decision variable n. They are all real and positive
Pn stands for every parameter n. They are all real and positive
Cn stands for every cost n

OF: min((V1-P1).C1-(V2-P2).C2+(V3-P3).C3

s.t.

(1) V3=min(max(V4, 0), max((V5-V6)+P4))

(2) V4=P5+V7-P6-V8

(3) V1+P4+(V5-V6) = V4+V2

My problem is set on restriction (1). I'm trying to convert it using aux varibles to define both max, so:

aux1>=0
aux1>=V4

aux2>=0
aux2>=(V5-V6)+P4)

So restriction (1) simplifies into V3=min(aux1, aux2)

Comment: The problem is that i can't maximize V3 into the min between the two max, i.e., V3 is always 0. So I then tried to create a third aux variable related to V3 to be maximized in the objective function. As in:

aux3 >= 0
aux3 <= V4
aux3 <= (V5-V6) + P4)
V3 >= aux3 

OF: min((V1-P1).C1 - (V2-P2).C2 + (V3-P3).C3 - aux3.C4

where C4 is a very small price.

It didn't really work because, as C4 is always smaller than C3, aux3 is always = 0.

I hope I've been clear. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Too difficult to read.

Comment: Sorry. Following your previous comment, the objective is a minimation of costs = ... + (x - x2).cost; s.t. x = min(y, z) where x2 is a parameter, x, y and z are opt variables, real and positive.

Comment: `x=min(y,z)` can be modeled using an extra binary variable.

Comment: Can't. My solver is NLP

Comment: There are MINLP solvers. Or run it twice. One with x=y and one with x=z. Pick the solution that obeys `x=min(y,z)`.